# Maximal subset $\{1,\dots,256\}$ with no pairs $x = 2y$

Tags: combinatorics

Let $A=\{1,\dots,256\}$. Find subset $A'\subset A$ with maximal elements s. t. there are no pairs $x=2y$.

My attempt is kind "including excluding formula": $256-128+64-\dots$

First take only odd numbers, the include half of even numbers (s. t. $4k$,  $k\in\mathbb N$) and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Divide the numbers into groups as follows. The first group contains $1,2,4,8, \dots,256$. The next group contains the numbers $3,6,12,24, 48,96,192$. The third consists of $5,10,20,40,80,160$. And so on.

The first group has an odd number of numbers, that is $9$. The maximum number of these we can take is $5$, starting at $1$. The second group has $7$ numbers, of which we can take a maximum of $4$, starting at $1$.  We can grab $3$ from the third group, starting at either $5$ or $10$. Let us choose to start at $5$.

The computation is not too bad, and it is clear that it will yield a set of maximal size.

But note the following: the procedure described above, if in the even case we start with the "base number" of the group, produces **exactly** what your suggestion produces. So your much easier way of counting does give us the maximum value of the size.

**Remark:** Note that your method does not pick out all  collections of maximum size, since in the groups $\{2^k (2b+1)\}$ that have an even number of elements, we have two choices of biggest subcollection. But it does identify the *size* of the largest possible collections.

Answer (score 1):

**Some suggestions:**

- These sets are called double-free sets, some more info can be found at [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Double-FreeSet.html).
- It is not a coincidence that the range of your starting set is $\{1,\ldots,2^8\}$.
- Let $a_n$ be the maximum size of such a set for range $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, then

  - you can safely take all the odds,
  - from the evens you cannot take these which are twice times some odd number,
  - from the rest, i.e. $4k$ for some $k$, you want to take best pick, which is the same problem as $a_{\lfloor n/4 \rfloor}$.
- In other words,$$a_{n} = \left\lceil n/2\right\rceil + a_\left\lfloor n/4\right\rfloor,\quad \text{ that is, } \quad a_{4k} = 2k + a_k.$$
- With some manipulation, you can simplify it to $a_n = n - a_{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}$, e.g. define $b_{n} = a_{n}-n+a_{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}$ and by induction
  \begin{align}
  b_{1} &= 0 \\
  b_{4k} &= a_{4k} - 4k + a_{2k} \\
         &= 2k+a_k - 4k + a_{2k} \\
         &= a_{2k}-2k+a_k \\
         &= b_{2k} = 0\\
  b_{4k+1} &= 2k+1 + a_k - (4k+1) + a_{2k} = b_{2k} = 0 \\
  b_{4k+2} &= 2k+1 + a_k - (4k+2) + a_{2k+1} = b_{2k+1} = 0\\
  b_{4k+3} &= 2k+2 + a_k - (4k+3) + a_{2k+1} = b_{2k+1} = 0
  \end{align}

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$